# sed: Dynamically remove all text columns except positions defined by pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

By searching and trying (no regex expert), I have managed to process a text output using sed or grep, and extract some lines, formatted this way:

```
Tree number 280:
1         0.500      1      node_15 6 --> H 1551.code
                     1      node_21 S ==> H node_20
Tree number 281:
1         0.500      1      node_16 S ==> M 1551.code
                     1      node_20 S --> H node_19
```

Then, using

`sed  's/^.\{35\}\(.\{9\}\).*/\1/' infile` , I get the desired part, plus some output which I get rid of later (not a problem).

```
Tree number 280:
 6 --> H 
 S ==> H 
Tree number 281:
 S ==> M
 S --> H
```

However, the horizontal position of the `C --> C` pattern may vary from file to file, although it is always aligned. Is there a way to extract the `-->` or `==>` including the single preceeding and following characters, no matter which columns they are found in?

The `Tree number #` part is not necessary and could be left blank as well, but there has to be a separator of a kind.

**UPDATE (alternative approach)**

Trying to use `grep`, I issued

`grep -Eo '(([a-zA-Z0-9] -- |[a-zA-Z0-9] ==)> [a-zA-Z0-9]|Changes)' infile`.

A sample of my initial file follows, if anyone thinks of a better, more efficient approach, or my use of regex is insane, please comment!

```
..MISC TEXT...

Character change lists:


Character    CI  Steps                  Changes
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         0.000      1         node_235 H --> S node
                     1         node_123 S ==> 6 1843
                     1         node_126 S ==> H 2461
                     1         node_132 S ==> 6 1863
                     1         node_213 H --> I 1816
                     1         node_213 H --> 8 1820
..CT...

Character change lists:

Character    CI  Steps                  Changes
----------------------------------------------------------------
1         0.000      1         node_165 H --> S node
                     1         node_123 S ==> 6 1843
                     1         node_231 H ==> S 1823
..MISC TEXT...
```

Comment: Well done, since Changes occurs first it will give you that as a column heading, and the regex restricts to letters and digits, if you want to simplify a little bit you can say [a-Z] for upper or lower case alphas.

Comment: grep -Eo '(([a-Z0-9] -- |[a-Z0-9] ==)> [a-Z0-9]|Changes)' infile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grep is a bit easier for just extracting the matching regex (if you need different separators you can add them to the list separated by pipes [-|=]

`grep -o '. [-|=][-|=]> .' infile`

Of if you really want to sed for this, this should do the first part matches only lines that have the pattern and the second part extracts only the matching regex

`sed -n '/[--|==]>/{s/.*\(. [=|-][-|=]> .\).*/\1/p}' infile`

Comment: Excellent, both work exactly as expected. The reason for using sed in the first place, was the convenience of using the -i switch to modify the same file. It might not be worth it, though, as I can also do it manually using grep.

Comment: The -i switch is useful from sed but imo sometimes (like if other people have to read it) its worthwhile to go for logical visual simplicity than the simplicity of the one-liner plus sed uses an intermediate file to implement the -i switch so internally you are at about the same complexity and performance doing something like grep statement < file > $$ && mv $$ file

Comment: Indeed, I just was trying to avoid multiple lines, because the commands are called from within R in order to preprocess the file. The other option would be importing it as plain text in R and doing it using its functions.